# Spring Mongo perform pagination/sorting with multiple collections

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am making use of org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query, with Pageable for all the regular search and pagination related feature. It is working fine, now i wanted to join multiple collections and do the pagination operations. Is there any provision for the same?

Thanks!

UPDATE
Please find the method which am using for achieving the same:

```
public <E> Page<E> searchEntity(final SearchCriteria searchCriteria, Pageable pageable, Class<E> entityClass) {
    Query query = prepareSearch(searchCriteria); // method which frames the required search criteria based on the requests
    long count = mongoOps.count(query, entityClass);
    if (count == 0) {
        return new PageImpl<>(new ArrayList<>(), pageable, 0);
    }
    query.with(pageable);
    List<E> list = mongoOps.find(query, entityClass);
    return new PageImpl<>(list, pageable, count);
}
```

Comment: if you can provide more details with an sample or example it would be better.
Definitely you can join multiple collections

Comment: @Lucia- I have updated the method using for the same.

Comment: The mongoDB supports join in the aggregation pipeline using $lookup stage.
So you have to use that when you are making your searchCriteria.

Comment: @Lucia - Can you share any references or a sample, where I can understand how the $lookup feature can be achieved using spring mongo.

Comment: https://newbedev.com/mongodb-lookup-in-spring-data-mongo

Comment: @Lucia - Thanks! Let me try it out.